# Concatenate values into unique values

Tags: excel, unique

I'm trying to make a range of unique values in Excel from a column of concatenated values, but every time I try I get `#Name error`. What am I doing wrong? I'm using this formula: `=listUnique(A$1:A$102916)`

Yes, I really do have 102,916 rows of data.

Comment: What module is `listUnique` defined in, and is it `Public`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by module... I'm new to Excel so I'm still learning the language. sorry.

Comment: Excel comes with a number of standard functions whose names are customarily written in uppercase; `listUnique` is not one of those. It also supports custom functions written in VBA, which are organized in modules within projects in the VBA editor, a separate window accessed by Alt-F11 or menu items. Each workbook comes with at least two predefined class modules, one for each sheet and one called `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way you can remove duplicates from the 102,916 rows you have in your `A` column:

```
= IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1)=1, A1, "")
```

Paste this formula into cell `B1` and then copy down all the way to row 102,916.  You will be left with only the unique values.  You can then copy these unique values and do a paste by value somewhere else if you need to.  FYI I checked that this formula works on concatenated values.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the REMOVE DUPLICATES functionality in VBA.

The code would look something like this for you:

```
Columns("A:A").Select    ' select column A
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$102916").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes ' for the active range, remove the duplicates; only 1 column selected; there is a header
```

You could copy the data to another column and do it that way if you wanted to avoid losing your concatenations.

Comment: Thank you Clauric. I will keep this in mind for next time.